# Disable cover page when printing from gimp

Tags: gimp, printing

If I print from `gimp` (version 2.6.11) I get always a cover page. If I print from other applications for example `gimp`, `libreoffice`, `firefox` or just from command line via `lpr` there is no cover page.

Is there a way to get rid of the cover page in `gimp`?

I use `ubuntu natty 11.04` and `cups` version `1.4.6-5ubuntu1.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out by myself: Just go in the printing dialogue to `Job` and select `None` at `Cover Page before` and `after` as on the following screenshot. `gimp` seems to remember this setting for other print jobs.

[image: screenshot]